# CriteriaAPI: selectCase when then...error in statement

Tags: sql, eclipselink, criteria-api

with the following code I get an error in my sql statement:

```
Expression<Number> difference = queryBuilder.diff(A, B);
Predicate differenceGEtoZero = queryBuilder.ge(difference, new Long(0));
CriteriaBuilder.Case<Number> when = queryBuilder.<Number>selectCase().when(
                differenceGEtoZero, difference
        );
        queryDefinition.select(
                queryBuilder.construct(
                        State.class,
                        root.get("object"),
                        queryBuilder.sum(
                                when.otherwise(new Long(0))
                        )
                )
        );
```

I get this sql statement containing an error in CASE'S THEN part:

```
SUM(
      CASE WHEN ((t1.A - t1.B) >= 0) 
      THEN ((t1.A - t1.B) >= 0)    //'>= 0'  should not appear here!!!
      ELSE 0 
      END )
```

I expected only the difference appearing ((t1.A - t1.B), not again a condition >=0.

I am using this version of the libs: org.apache.openejb:javaee-api:6.0-5 and eclipseLink 2.3.2 as provider

Could you please tell me what's wrong in the code?

Thank you in advance.
Nic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a bug solved by following versions of eclipseLink.

With `2.5.1` everything is working fine.